# Как сделать так, чтобы высота input регулировалась в зависимости от содержимого?

Tags: html, input

Собсно есть на странице Input, хочу сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию в нем располагался только placeholder, а при вводе мне необходимо, чтобы он отслеживал свое содержимое и, в случае необходимости, увеличивал/уменьшал свою высоту. Как добиться оного?

Comment: Высоту? Шрифт меняется что ли?

Comment: нет, в <input type="text" /> можно ли замутить, чтобы он переносы делал и соответственно высоту свою увеличивал/уменьшал?

Comment: Тогда Вам к `textarea`, он для этого и создан.

Comment: @Other, но в texarea можно вводить многострочный текст. К тому же, она тоже так себе за размерами следит.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну переносов в `input` нельзя делать, если нужны - `textarea` поможет. А так - неясно что автору надо.

Comment: @Other, он в комментарии уже написал же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, угу, и ценного для понимания там ровно ничего.

Comment: @Other, пример с contenteditable почти работает)

Comment: @Qwertiy, однако это не `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: @Other, да. Но работает так как описано.

Answer (score 2):

Можно обычный див с `contenteditable=true` и стилем `display: inline-block`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true></div>
```

Comment: Если уж делать `contenteditable`, то [так](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988), только с `white-space: normal`.

Comment: @Qwertiy че-т я не пойму в чем разница тогда. у тебя стили `.editor *` для кроссбраузерности добавлены или что это?

Comment: Для того, чтобы вот такого не было: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsC3d.gif

Answer (score -2):

может в CSS

```
input{
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Да ну? А проверь.